# datatables.js is munging the rendered output

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have the wierdest thing happening.  I have the following code segment:

```
$('#workQueueTable').DataTable({
    "data": requests,
    "columns": [
        { "title": "Project ID", "data":"ProjectID", "render": function(data) {
                return '<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="getDataFromSP("FormByID", "' + data + '")"' + '>' + data + '</a>';
                }  
        },
        { "title": "Project Description", "data": "Title", "sWidth": "50%" },
        { "title": "Date Requested", "data": "DateRequested", "sWidth": "10%", "render": function(data) {
            return (data.getMonth()+1) + '/' + data.getDate() + '/' + data.getFullYear();
        } },
        { "title": "Stage", "data": "Stage", "sWidth": "15%" }
    ]
});
```

That should put out a simple url like:

```
<a href='javascript:void();' onclick="getDataFromSP("FormByID", "PR012393")>PR012393</a>
```

but what I get is:

```
<a onclick="getDataFromSP(" href="javascript:void();" FormByID?,="" ?PR-NewReq?)?="">
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.
JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line instead:

```
return '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="getDataFromSP(\'FormByID\', \'' + data + '\')">' + data + '</a>'
```

Using `&quot;` is the only way to use double quotes in attribute value enclosed by double quotes. For example `onclick="getData(&quot;value&quot;)"`.

However, it just easier to use single-quotes instead. However you need to escape them as `\'` so that these quotes doesn't end the string they are enclosed in, because you're also using single quotes to define a string.

Comment: That has got it!  Thank you.  Please help me understand why this works.

Comment: @JDSanders, added more details.

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
return '<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="getDataFromSP("FormByID", "' + data + '")"' + '>' + data + '</a>'
```

to

```
return '<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="getDataFromSP(\"FormByID\", \"' + data + '\")"' + '>' + data + '</a>'
```

You have to escape the `"` character, otherwise it will exit the `onclick` property earlier than expected.

Edit:

Try changing the `"` with `'`

```
return '<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="getDataFromSP(\'FormByID\', \'' + data + '\')">' + data + '</a>'
```

Comment: I did try that and tried it again based on your suggestion and still get:  <a onclick="getDataFromSP(" href="javascript:void();" FormByID?,="" ?PR-NewReq?)?="">

Comment: if I store it in a variable it is perfect.  if I pass the variable to the return it still gets munged.  It has got to be dataTables.js doing it.  Any thoughts on another way of doing it?

Comment: Can you please show us the result of outputting it from a variable?